# Postgresql - Looping based on timestamp

Tags: postgresql-11

i am working on a scenario where need to run a particular code block for 5 mins.
I tried various options but no luck till now.
Could you please guide me.

Attaching the half-baked block:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE 
    i         int;
    startTime TIMESTAMP;
    endTime   TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    i := 1;
    startTime := now();
    endTime := now() + (1 * interval '5 minute');
    RAISE NOTICE 'City Name:(%)(%)',statement_timestamp(),now() + (1 * interval '5 minute');

    WHILE  statement_timestamp() < endTime LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'City Name:(%)(%)(%)',endTime,now(), statement_timestamp();
        -- example:
        --create table if not exists test12345(id int,start_dt TIMESTAMP,end_dt TIMESTAMP);
        insert into test12345 
        select i,startTime,endTime;
        
        --RAISE NOTICE startTime;
        RAISE NOTICE 'City Name:(%)', statement_timestamp();

        --startTime := statement_timestamp();

    END LOOP;

END;
$do$;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to use `clock_timestamp()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks. It started working.